# Sending emails using XAMPP and PHP using Mac Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, apache, email, xampp

I am really confused on where to start with sending emails. I have search the web but the amount of content available for different packages and softwares has really confused me. I was wondering if anyone here had a simple or knows of a simple tutorial of how i can send an email using xampp.

Im new to using local host and so far have only used MySQL and Apache from xampp to load and view my php files for an application.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me start setting up XAMPP to send emails when i use the php.

Some sites suggest a separate server is needed for emails such as PHPMailer while others suggest a few config changes need making like changing in the php.ini files which I'm very cautious to change incase my whole xampp crashes!

is this link any good? http://www.websnippetz.com/2013/01/send-email-from-xampp-localhost.html
Many are using SendMail package with XAMPP but i can't find a download for that.

anyone tried anything which worked for them?

please help a very confused developer guys!

Answer (score 1):

> Some sites suggest a separate server is needed for emails such as PHPMailer while others suggest a few config changes need making like changing in the php.ini files which I'm very cautious to change incase my whole xampp crashes!

PHPMailer is not a server it is a library. People often recommend using a Mail library because the built mail functions are very low level and hard to work with. Because they are modeled after using [`sendmail` from the commandline](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sendmail.1.html).

If you want to send via SMTP, use attachments, or other things it can be difficult or impossible to do with `mail()` directly.

Personally I recommend using SwiftMail over PHP mailer. IMO, it's more modern, easier to use, and has a better API, and depending on which PHP F/OSS projects you are used to using or contributing to its more common and the standard.

Overall there are 2 parts to sending mail from PHP:

1. Setup of the actual mail server on a system (local or otherwise)
2. The configuration of PHP to use that mail server.

To setup the `mail` function you need to install and configure a mail server locally in order to fulfill item (1). This should already be included and set up on OSX. So to fulfill item (2) you need to configure PHP via the INI to use that mail server by changing the [`sendmail_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path).

Now if you want to use a library, which I recommend you need to get that source into your project and then use it appropriately. For the example we will use SwiftMailer, with SMTP transport via a gmail account:

```
require_once 'PATH/TO/swift_required.php';

// Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.googlemail.com', 465, 'ssl')
  ->setUsername('user@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('secret');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('My SMTP Message')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receipient@domain.com', 'other@domain.com' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Plain Text Message Body');

$mailer->send($message);
```

Comment: Ive read somewhere that mac has a postfix server already set up by default. i found this link. http://www.developerfiles.com/how-to-send-smtp-mails-with-postfix-mac-os-x-10-8/ is this any good?

Comment: That should be fine if you really want to configure Postfix, but you shouldn't need to...

Comment: I don't really want to configure anything. I just want to use what i have already in xampp and just amend that for it to work. Not sure how to do that part. really appreciate your help

Comment: So take look at your `php.ini` at the `sendmail_path` make sure it points `/usr/sbin/sendmail` (there will/should be a couple of command line options) and then use the `mail()` function or use SwiftMailer with `Mail` transport.

Comment: currently it is set as ';sendmail_path =' so i just need to add that to the path to the end of it? and remove the semi-colon? what about stating the email address and password like @Stony showed above?

Comment: this is all thats there for the UNIX bit: " ; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path ="

Comment: No, that is only for windows. *nix does not support setting up SMTP transport via these settings.

Comment: Yes that is correct... OS X is essentially a unix system when it comes to things like this. you can open up Terminal.app and do `which sendmail` to make sure its installed and get the path to it.

Comment: brilliant so i've done that and restarted the servers. So now i should create a simple form and try out the swift mailer code?

Comment: Well you need to use slightly different code ([see here](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#the-mail-transport)) but yes. You might want to try just using the [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function first though for testing.

Comment: do i need to download the swiftMail framework for the mail() function to work?

Comment: No... separate things.

Answer (score 0):

To send emails from your localhost your need an Email-Server like postfix or Exim or you send your E-Mails over SMTP what is described on that site from your link.

The easiest way is to use an abstraction layer like Swift Mailer

http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html

Here you have a lot of possibilities to send E-Mails. Another solution is to install a local Mailserver and fetch all sending E-Mails. In MAMP Pro for example you have an integrated Mailserver.

http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/how-to-sending-emails-with-mamp-pro.html